# Open Local Network file from hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink

My requirement is to open a file from the local network folder when clicked on a button or hyperlink. I tried the following but it is not working. it is just opening the same record page in new window.

Workaround I tried :
For creating a link to a network/local file,

1. Create a text field (for example, with the following name: "Path")
2. Create formula field with data type: Text (for example, with the following name: "File")  to link to that file:

HYPERLINK("file://"&{!Path__c},"View")

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this will only works with IE. Due to the security model of other browser it will open the same record link.

To get it to work: add the Salesforce domain "https://salesforce.com" and "https://test.salesforce.com" (the site MUST be https) to the trusted sites section in Internet Options.